# How to get persistent input in SDL2 c++

Tags: c++, input, sdl-2

So I noticed that when getting input with `SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL)`, when holding a specific button, it is going to first write outlets say `a`, and after 1 second its gonna continue `aaaaaaaa` normally. I want to when I hold the button a that it automatically goes `aaaaaa`.
Here is a video if you don't understand my poor explanations:
https://streamable.com/oub0w3

There is a delay between it writes out first `a`, and writing out `aaaaa` about 1 second. How can I change that? (I want there to be no delay)

Here is my code:

```
while (gameRunning) {
    SDL_Event event;
    const Uint8* keystates = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            gameRunning = false;
        }
        if (keystates[SDL_SCANCODE_W]) {
            entities[0].setY(entities[0].getY() - 1);
        }
        if (keystates[SDL_SCANCODE_S]) {
            entities[0].setY(entities[0].getY() + 1);
        }
        if (keystates[SDL_SCANCODE_A]) {
            entities[0].setX(entities[0].getX() - 1);
        }
        if (keystates[SDL_SCANCODE_D]) {
            entities[0].setX(entities[0].getX() + 1);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misusing `SDL_GetKeyboardState(nullptr)`.

It should be used in the main loop, not in the event loop:

```
while (gameRunning)
{
    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            gameRunning = false;
    }
    const std::uint8_t *keystates = SDL_GetKeyboardState(nullptr);
    if (keystates[SDL_SCANCODE_W])
        entities[0].setY(entities[0].getY() - 1);
    if (keystates[SDL_SCANCODE_S])
        entities[0].setY(entities[0].getY() + 1);
    // An so on...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was mashing my head into the wall trying to figure it out and it was this simple

Comment: Additional note: I believe the only reason why OP's program *happened to work* the way it did is because Windows posts repeated `WM_KEYDOWN` messages to the message queue, which causes OP's `while (SDL_PollEvent(...))` loop to run at least once during that frame, which happens to execute the code that reads the `keystates` array. And because `SDL_PollEvents` pumps the message queue internally, the `keystates` also happened to get updated correctly if the state of a key ever changes. Threoretically, OP's code should behave differently while moving the mouse (since that also generates messages).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the repetition to start immediately, you need to make your own implementation of the repeating letters.

The additional "a" characters you receive as events are (I assume) generated by the operating system, so unless you have some settings on your OS you can change to make repetition start immediately, you need your program to do it.

*(I am assuming SDL is not the one generating these characters, which could be a possibility)*

To do this, you would make a system check the amount of time elapsed and kept track of how long keys are being pressed, and outputting "key" events that it generated itself, much like the OS is doing.